# Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback alternative in SharpDX

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, directx, windows-phone-8.1, sharpdx

I want to play a video, and this is how it is done in DirectX:

```
Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.Video video = new Video(fileName);
video.Owner = panel1;
video.Play();
```

But I can't find `AudioVideoPlayback` in [`SharpDX`](http://sharpdx.org/), the DirectX API for .NET.

Is it supported in SharpDX? Any tip is appreciated.

Comment: What is the reason you need SharpDX? You are already using managed DirectX 9 code in your sample above.

Comment: @NextInLine I want to use it in Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 .. managed DirectX seems to not be supported.

Comment: Yes, managed directX support was dropped almost a decade ago. Is there a reason you need DirectX rather than the XAML-based video playback options available in Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1?

Comment: @NextInLine I want to play video files like MKV, FLV etc.. I don't know if I have other options too?

Answer (score 0):

For playing video in Windows 8.1 store apps and Windows Phone 8.1, the preferred method is using the XAML tools Microsoft provides in their framework that makes this fairly simple. See [Quickstart: video and audio (XAML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465160.aspx) for more details.

**Managed DirectX** was released in 2002[[1]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_DirectX) and based on DirectX 9. It has been deprecated for a while, which is why for users of managed code, libraries like **SharpDX** exist to provide a managed wrapper around the unmanaged (C++). In Windows Store and Windows 8.1 phone apps, DirectX 11 is required, which is why Managed DirectX wasn't working for you.

Comment: The problem with built-in `MediaElement` is that it doesn't support mkv, flv etc.. that's why I am trying to find alternatives.

Comment: You should probably update your original question with what you have looked at that doesn't work for your use case (and the information that you need to play mkv, flv, etc). See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more info.

Comment: Thanks. Anyway it is clear I think, I can't find that namespace in SharpDX.

Comment: Yes, you would have to figure out how to do it in unmanaged DirectX 11 and then search SharpDX for the equivalent assemblies. So if you are looking for the SharpDX equivalent of the unmanaged `ID3D11Device`, [search google with *site:sharpdx.org documentation id3d11device*](https://www.google.com/webhp?#q=site:sharpdx.org+documentation+id3d11device). I suspect unless Windows Store Apps natively support those encodings though, you will also have to write a decoder for those file types, which is probably a lot of work.